# How to reference a WPF .NET Core dll in WPF .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

From Visual Studio 2019, I've created a WPF project in .NET Core. The project name is `test1`.

The dll of `test1` project is added in WPF .NET framework from Visual Studio 2017 using reference option.

[image]

After adding dll, I tried to call MainWindow from Test project in .NET Framework

```
var test = new Test.MainWindow()
test.SHowdialog()
```

When I tried to run it, I got the below error. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can't reference a .net core dll in a .net framework project

Comment: you can change the class library to target dotnet standard 2.0 which is compatible with dotnet core and dotnet framework.

Comment: @VilsadPP WPF is not available in .NET Standard

Comment: @Chaya If it's a new project, I would recomend stay away from .NET Framework, as it'll not receive new versions. .NET Core (renamed to just .NET, starting in .NET 5, november this year) will be the only .NET going forward: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/